# Can a ferrite choke/bead suppress unwanted audio signals (maybe mobile phone induced)?

Tags: audio, interference, choke

I use a headset with a normal 3.5mm audio cable (not USB). Most times I have excellent audio quality, but in a large office building, I sometimes get very bad signals injected from an unknown source. I do not hear them myself, it's only affecting the microphone - a very lound buzz/humm. Needless to say, it is hopeless to identify the source as I don't have access to all rooms or even all floors. It *may* be the "usual" interference coupled from mobile phones.

Would one of the usual ferrite beads https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ferrite_bead_no_shell.jpg likely help with audio signals? Or do those beads only make sense in high frequenzy (1xx kHz/MHz) ranges?

Comment: Ferrite beads can be used to reduce the radio interference.  They have no effect on audio.  If radio interference is causing the noise, then ferrite beads will reduce the radio interference that causes the noise.  You can't use a ferrite bead to remove the audio noise once it is there.  You have to remove the radio interference with the ferrite bead at the point where the radio interference was getting into your audio lines.

Comment: As JRE comments, ferrite beads will do **nothing** for your buzz/humm problem. Buzz and Humm is actually a low frequency usually coming form the 120V / 240 V mains. It depends on the design of the headset and the PC you're connecting to if it is an issue. If possible try with a laptop on battery power and see if that helps. If not or a laptop is not an option I see little other solution but using a better quality headset.

Comment: I do not think that a better headset would change anything. Mains can not be picked up after the signal is amplified to headphone impedance, the problem is most likely before in the chain.

Comment: @jre etc al: the problem even occurs if I connect the headset to a smartphone directly, so it is not mains. It can come and go during the same call, so I assume (but who knows?) that it is not caused by my own phone transmission. That said, if I understand you correctly, a bead should stop the cable functioning as an antenna , yes?

Comment: Looping the headset cable through a snap on ferrite bead can help, but depends on where the radio interference is getting in.  If the radio interference is getting into the cable and causing a buzz through the phone, a ferrite will probably help.  If the radio interference is getting through the electronics in the microphone, then a ferrite won't do you any good.

Comment: Is the buzz/hum at 60Hz or 120Hz or......at the Bluetooth RF packet frequency (577Hz?)

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, I still have to hear it myself - it is always creeping up when I really want to use it, but seems elusive when I do tests (talking with myself with the help of another phone :D ). But Bluetooth is a very good idea! I will make sure to disable any bluetooth receivers close to me to see if it makes a difference. And no, it is not the 50/100Hz I would get from mains here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how helpful in general, but I'll share my experience. Over 15 years ago I have bought a usb condenser mic. Samson c01u to be precise. For those 15 years Ive had it, it was always a bad experience. I had good days with great audio, and worse days, and I can not remember a time when I wouldn't have some sort of hum or buzz.

I am currently using a MacBook, and as stupid as it sounds, Ive even tried to place my finger on the laptop while recording, and that helped reduce some humming while recording. Not perfect. Even more noticeable when you use a noise suppressor. Ive even contacted Samson to help me figure out a solution as I am using their usb cable to this day. You'd expect them to think of these issues when selling you a product.

Ive heard of a Ferrite choke but didn't have a cable at home that had one. Yesterday at work, the receding studio was having things thrown out, and I saw a cable I need in the pile, exactly the one I need, so I took it home.

Decided to do some recording tests. plugged my original cable and buzzing and humming, then the shorter cable with the built in Ferrite choke, and WOW. 15 years later I got rid of the hum and buzz problem. I don't want to jinx it, but I cannot believe I am getting clean audio with no interference.

I still don't know if there is anything else its suppressing, but so far, no humming ir buzzing.

Comment: This does not answer the asked question. It's likely not the ferrite bead that makes any difference as they don't work at audio frequencies.

Comment: @Justme It seems unlikely that the question is about audio frequencies per se, but rather radio frequencies causing audio-band interference (e.g. input rectification). It's entirely possible that the answered solution would have some value for situations like this. EMC problems being what they are, there's no way to know for sure, and OP didn't provide nearly enough information to know for sure whether it would, but the possibility seems to leave some merit. Alternately, perhaps this question should be closed (notice bot bump today) for lack of information?